# swfobject not working?

Tags: javascript, youtube, swfobject

hey guys,
i wonder what i'm doing wrong.

index.html

```
<script src="swfobject/swfobject.js"type="text/javascript"></script>

<div class="post">
    <script type="text/javascript">

        var params = { allowScriptAccess: "always" };
        var atts = { id: "myytplayer" };
        swfobject.embedSWF("http://www.youtube.com/e/GfugtAWxooU?enablejsapi=1&playerapiid=ytplayer",
                           "ytapiplayer", "425", "356", "8", null, null, params, atts);

      </script>
</div>
```

my swfobject folder is in the same directory as my index.html. Why can't i see anything. I've already tested in online (not just local). http://jsfiddle.net/RsJbv/

thank you

Comment: You *do* understand that you need an `HTML` element with `id` `ytapiplayer` for it to work, don't you?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are dynamically embedding a youtube video by swfobject. You need an element with id `ytapiplayer` that will "wrap" the video. Basically, you have to say to swfobject where to load the `swf` => http://jsfiddle.net/steweb/czEF9/

```
swfobject.embedSWF("SWFURL","elementID", "width", "height", "8", null, null, params, atts);
```

`elementID` is the id of your DOM element (it MUST exists) ;)

Comment: thank you, perfect. One more quick question. Any idea why my controls won't work? http://jsfiddle.net/czEF9/1/

Comment: Np, your functions are inside a domready event (it's not visible). Above the framework selection, there is the wrapping code options. Select "no wrap". Btw, it would be good to set clicks directly by jQuery => http://jsfiddle.net/steweb/FYXVD/

Comment: perfect, thank you! And the absolutely last question :) How can i add an eventListener to the video? The youtube api provides $('#ytplayer').addEventListener('onStateChange', 'alert'); to check if the state of the video is changed. Why does that not fire? http://jsfiddle.net/FYXVD/1/ Thank you for your awesome help.

Comment: To check the state, you need to unwrap the code and add event listener once the video is loaded i.e. => http://jsfiddle.net/steweb/Z9Zvd/ (do NOT assign reserved keywords - alert - as function names ;) )

Comment: P.s. 'onYouTubePlayerReady' is a callback function automatically called (if you declare it) once the video is loaded...

Comment: you're absolutely awesome! +100 for that. However what to do if i have multiple videos and i want to pause a currently playing video if i start a new one. http://jsfiddle.net/Z9Zvd/1/ This is actually what i'm looking for. I don't want to have two videos playing at the same time. When one is playing and i play a new one, the other one should pause. Thank you for your amazing help. And sorry for my annoying questions.

Comment: any idea how i could solve that? i have dynamically generated playerId's. How can i check if a video is ready if i don't know the videoId before?

Comment: Hey pal, sozz.. I was out of office.. 2 mins and I'll check your questions :)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/steweb/yqy6d/ ok.. now I think you have everything to achieve everything you want to do :)

Comment: why: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5008234/dynamically-inserting-swfobject-with-php-dont-get-it

Comment: @steweb: how about this example! shouldn't that actually work? http://jsfiddle.net/PU82V/ I'm applying a class to every video - works fine. I want every videoplayer to be unMuted() and have a onStateChanged function applied.

Comment: @mathiregister check my website (on my profile) and send me an email.. I don't have time right now ;)

Comment: @mathiregister loool I'm sorry pal, I deleted the spam messages (your mail was inside the spam folder). Re-send it plz :)

Comment: Why am i getting this error : "Microsoft JScript runtime error: 'swfobject' is undefined" ??, although i have my scripts on the  head , and im passing all the arguments right ??